# Delete/remove part of message on discord.py

Tags: python, bots

Actually, i have a script who start a bot, who find a link on message posted on discord, and resend it with modified url. I want to remove just link on original message, and replace it by new modified link. Finally, it send original message only with new link.
This is my script:

```
async def on_message(message):
    author_bf = message.author.id
    if message.author.id == "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" and message.channel.id == XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
        return
    if "amazon.fr" in message.content and message.channel.id == XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and not "tag=" in message.content:
        urls = re.findall("(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'.,<>?«»“”‘’]))?", message.content)
        if urls:
            for x in range(len(urls)):
                print(urls[x])
                affi_link = str(urls[x])+("?tag=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                await message.delete(urls)
                await message.channel.send("<@"+str(author_bf)+">"+"\n"+str(affi_link))
```

Actually, this script not work. Error is:

```
delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
```

Anyone know how to make this please? Thank you!!

EDIT: Test with message.content.replace(urls, "") and add new link, but not work.

EDIT2: await message.delete(message) delete full message, i just want to delete url in message content only

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just try:

```
await message.delete(message)
```

Comment: Thanks, but It's not really what i want. I want just to delete only url in message, and replace it by another. I want to save message content without url before, and add new.

Comment: I think, you gonna have to do it with another approach, because you cant edit the messages of other users. 
Maybe you should try to get the url out of the original message, than delete it. Afterwards you just send the new link with the bot.